# Using Play and Pause video

Tags: javascript, button, video, playback

I hope you can help me. I have a button for Play and other Pause but dont work.
Thanks. This is my code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Video.js | HTML5 Video Player</title>
    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/3.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/3.2/video.js"></script>
    <script>
        _V_.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
    </script>
    <script>    
        _V_("example_video_1").ready(function(){   
            var myPlayer = this;
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" data-setup="{}">
        <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
        <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
        <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
    </video>
    <input type="button" value="Pause" onClick="myPlayer.pause();">
    <input type="button" value="Play" onClick="myPlayer.play();">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/faq you need a little more info about where you are trying to run you code.

Answer (score 0):

The video setup has to happen after the document is loaded. So, you have to include it inside an "onload" function. If you are using jQuery, you may put it inside `$(document).ready()`. Otherwise you can use `window.onload`. Also you'll have to remove the "var" keyword, as inside a function it creates a local variable, that you cannot access from outside.

So the setup script would become:

```
<script>  
    window.onload = function(){
       _V_("example_video_1").ready(function(){ 
          myPlayer = this; 
       });
   };
</script>
```